# TensorFlow DataSet shuffle - data shuffling only starting from second epoch

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am using the tensorflow DataSet for input data pipeline. I am wondering how to run training without data shuffling in first epoch and start shuffling data from the second epoch.

the graph is usually built before iterative training start and during training it seems not straight-forward how to change the DataSet shuffling behavior since it looks to me kinds of like changing the graph.

any idea?

thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 0):

The `buffer_size` argument to [`Dataset.shuffle()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) can be a computed `tf.Tensor`, so you can use the following code that uses `Dataset.range(NUM_EPOCHS).flat_map(...)` to transform a sequence of epoch numbers to the (shuffled or otherwise) elements of a `per_epoch_dataset`:

```
NUM_EPOCHS = ...  # The total number of epochs.
BUFFER_SIZE = ...  # The shuffle buffer size to use from the second epoch on.

per_epoch_dataset = ...  # A `Dataset` representing the elements of a single epoch.

def shuffle_after_first_epoch(epoch):
  # Set `epoch_buffer_size` to 1 (i.e. no shuffling) in the 0th epoch,
  # and `BUFFER_SIZE` thereafter.
  epoch_buffer_size = tf.cond(tf.equal(epoch, 0),
                              lambda: tf.constant(1, tf.int64),
                              lambda: tf.constant(BUFFER_SIZE, tf.int64))
  return per_epoch_dataset.shuffle(epoch_buffer_size)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(NUM_EPOCHS).flat_map(shuffle_after_first_epoch)
```

Comment: Thank you mrry! I am not sure I quite get what flat_map achieves. I guess in this case I do not need dataset.repeat(num_epoch) anymore?

Comment: That's correct. `flat_map()` is like a nested `for` loop wrapped around a loop over `per_epoch_dataset` that yields each element.

Comment: Great! Really appreciate the help mrry! Thanks!

Comment: Hi mrry, an extra question along this direction, I want to put dataset.batch() before flat_map(), by doing this, I support the behavior should be that batches are not shuffled in the first epoch but from the second epoch, is it right?

Comment: Putting `.batch()` literally before the `flat_map()` (i.e. doing `Dataset.range(...).batch(...).flat_map(...)`) would batch the epoch IDs, which is not what I suspect you want to do. The most appropriate place to put a `.batch()` would be at `return per_epoch_dataset.shuffle(epoch_buffer_size).batch(...)`, and then you'd get non-shuffled batches for the first epoch, and shuffled batches for all subsequent epochs.

Comment: thanks. I was actually saying do per_epoch_dataset = per_epoch_dataset.batch(), and no change to def shuffle_after_first_epoch, and then dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(NUM_EPOCHS).flat_map(shuffle_after_first_epoch),  my understanding is, it is the same as modifying shuffle_after_first_epoch by return per_epoch_dataset.batch(...).shuffle(epoch_buffer_size) right?  say for some reason I want to batch first (no within-batch shuffle) and random shuffle the batch.

Comment: OK, that will produce the same set of batches in each epoch, but the batches will be produced in a shuffled order from the second epoch onwards.

Comment: good, really appreciate your time to help, thanks a lot mrry!